# Bind @Input() field in components template

Tags: angular

I have a component like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  template: '<h1>{{bar}}</h1>'
})
export class FooComponent {
  @Input()
  bar: string;
}
```

Now I'd like to use this component somewhere else (assuming everything is correctly configured):

```
<foo [bar]="Test"></foo>
```

The output is:

```
<h1></h1>
```

Do you know why? Why can't a `@Input()` field be bound in it's components template?

Version: Angular 2.0 Final Release

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be

```
<foo [bar]="'Test'"></foo>
```

or

```
<foo bar="Test"></foo>
```

otherwise the value of property `Test` of the parent component will be assigned, which is probably `undefined`.